# ExtJS Toolbar: how keep an item always directly accesible, never put in the "more" menu

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

I have an ExtJS toolbar at the top of my panel that can have between 5 and 10 actions (buttons), plus a search text field as the last item.

Depending on the size of the window, all items may fit directly on the toolbar, or some of them may get put into a "more" menu button. I need to specify one of those button to have some sort of priority so it is the last one to be put on the "more" button. Or even to never be put on it.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by wrapping the toolbar in a container like this:

```
tbar: [
  {
     xtype: 'container',
     layout: {
       type: 'hbox',
       pack: 'start',
       align: 'stretch'
     },
     items: [
       {
          xtype: 'mail-compose-toolbar',
          flex: 1
       },
       {
         xtype: 'mail-compose-search',
         itemId: 'mailComposeSearch',
         width: 200
       }
     ]
  }
]
```

The search field is of fixed width and the toolbar has a flex:1 so it stretches.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Add items with code. I don't know if this is exactly your case, but I often use this to arrange buttons in toolbar:

**Working example:**

```
Ext.onReady(function(){

    Ext.QuickTips.init();
    Ext.FocusManager.enable();
    Ext.Ajax.timeout = 100 * 1000;

    Ext.define('Trnd.TestWindow', {
        extend: 'Ext.window.Window',

        closeAction: 'destroy',
        border: false,
        width: 400,
        height: 500,
        modal: true,
        closable: true,
        resizable: true,
        layout: 'fit',

        fillToolbar: function() {
            var me = this;

            me.toolbar.add(me.button5);
            me.toolbar.add(me.button1);
            me.toolbar.add(me.button2);
            me.toolbar.add(me.button3);
            me.toolbar.add(me.edit);
            me.toolbar.add(me.button4);
        },

        initComponent: function() {
            var me = this;
            me.callParent(arguments);

            me.button1 = Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', {
                text: 'Button 1'
            });
            me.button2 = Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', {
                text: 'Button 2'
            });
            me.button3 = Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', {
                text: 'Button 3'
            });
            me.button4 = Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', {
                text: 'Button 4'
            });
            me.button5 = Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', {
                text: 'Button 5'
            });
            me.edit = Ext.create('Ext.form.TextField', {
                text: 'Edit'
            });

            me.toolbar = Ext.create('Ext.toolbar.Toolbar', {
                enableOverflow: true,
                items: []
            });

            me.panel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
                tbar: me.toolbar
            });

            me.add(me.panel);

            me.fillToolbar();
        }

    }); 


    var win = new Trnd.TestWindow({

    });
    win.show();

});
```

**Notes:**

Tested with ExtJS 4.2

Comment: This works as a basic Toolbar, but there is nothing there that would leave the TextField always visible. Reduce the window and the TextField is the first one to be put away.